MongoDB update or create subfield
I want to update or push a product in the products list,
for better performence im filtering by date/hours[hour]/categories[category] EX:
   {
    date: "05/05/24",
    "hours.hour": "09",
    "hours.categories.category": "computers",
    "hours.categories.products": {
      $elemMatch: { product_source_id: 112233},
    }
   }

If path exists I want to update the product,
if some of the path like hours/category/etc.. doesnt exist I want to create it.
"upsert" does not help me cuz it just creates a whole new document but I want to modify the existing one
this is the Document Sceham
  date: { type: String, required: true },
  hours: [
    {
      hour: { type: String, enum: hoursEnum },
      categories: [
        {
          category: { type: String, required: true },
          products: [
            {
              product_source_id: { type: String, required: true },
              last_published: { type: Date, required: true },
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ]

Im using mongoose

It seems Iv`e been wrong from the start
I should simplify the the document to be shallow(less nested keys) and use "Index" for performent searches
